# UserScript not running as a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Here is my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Javascript  
// @version    0.1
// @match      *://*/*
// @include    *://*/*
$('*').contents().filter(function() {return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && this.nodeValue.trim() != '';}).each(function() {this.nodeValue = (atob('TWljaGFlbCBpcyBiYWUh '));});
```

The script does, indeed, work when ran in the javascript console. I want it to run on all pages. I'm using it by dragging the .user.js file containing this into chrome://extensions.

Comment: Have you tried [Tempermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a more temporary/fast solution. It works in tampermonkey fine.